# How to overwrite the default JSON response in Spring boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

My spring boot application returning below json response when controller responds with 400-BadRequest.

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\r\n  \"success\" : false,\r\n  \"projects\" :null,\r\n  \"httpStatusCode\" : \"400\",\r\n  \"message\" : \"Request  Processing failed.\",\r\n  \"requestErrors\" : [ {\r\n    \"error\" : \"platform required.\"\r\n  }, {\r\n    \"error\" : \"id required.\"\r\n  }, {\r\n    \"error\" : \"name required.\"\r\n  } ]\r\n}",
"responseJSON": {
"success": false,
"projects": null,
"httpStatusCode": "400",
"message": "Request Processing failed.",
"requestErrors": [
  {
    "error": "platform required."
  },
  {
    "error": "id required."
  },
  {
    "error": "name required."
  }
]
},
 "status": 400,
 "statusText": "Bad Request" 
}
```

But here i dont want to see json elements `responseText`, `status`, and `statusText`, since my JSON object itself having these information.

Here is my `CustomErrorAttributes` class.

```
public class CustomErrorAttribute implements ErrorAttributes {
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
    Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    errorAttributes.put("timestamp", new Date());
    return errorAttributes;
}

@Override
public Throwable getError(RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {
    return new IllegalStateException("Illegal State of the request.");
}
}
```

Java Config:

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes customErrorAttribute(){
    return new CustomErrorAttribute();
}
```

I tried with registering custom implementation of `ErrorAttributes` as `@Bean` as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350445/where-does-the-default-json-errors-response-in-spring-boot-starter-web-comes-fro)

But no luck, please any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are configuring `ErrorAttributes`?

Comment: Hello @geoand updated question with `ErrorAttributes` implementation.

Comment: Do you have any bean of type `ErrorAttributes` configured?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make Spring aware of your `CustomErrorAttribute` implementation.

Just add a configuration class (or simply add the `@Bean` part to one of your existing Spring configuration classes) like:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcErrorConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomErrorAttribute errorAttributes() {
        return new CustomErrorAttribute();
    }

}
```

and everything works out of the box.

[This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) part of the documentation has all the details.
The relevant Spring Boot autoconfiguration class is `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`

Comment: I am sure `CustomErrorAttribute` is Spring aware, since i am able to autowire it.  githug link to my project https://github.com/lovababu/SpringBootExample

Comment: Ok, I run the project and get back to you

Comment: The error handling in your project is working out of the box for me. The `CustomErrorAttribute` class is being used correctly by Spring. Perhaps you should perform a `gradle clean` and see what happens

Comment: I should also mention that the code worked when I ran the main class via the IDE, or using `Gradle`.

Comment: You meant to say, are you getting response without those json element aforementioned? I did clean and ran the main through IDE, but no luck still same response.

Comment: Yes, the only attribute present in the response was the timestamp, nothing else. Actually, I only tested the HTTP 404 scenario. I haven't checked the HTTP 400 scenario. I'll do that now

Comment: Ok, I tried posting `{}` to `/projects`, and what I got in response was:

`{
"success": false,
"projects": null,
"httpStatusCode": "400",
"message": "Request Processing failed.",
"requestErrors":[
{
"error": "platform required."
},
{
"error": "name required."
},
{
"error": "description required."
},
{
"error": "id required."
}
]
}`

Comment: Sorry @geoand it seems [jsondoc](http://jsondoc.org/) is miss lead me. when i sent request through chrome postman i see expected response, but not with jsondoc ui. Thanks for your help.