# JS Fetch Catch from Spring Controller Exception not executed due to Spring Boot's BasicControllerException JSON output

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot Controller throws an Exception, but on the JS Fetch side, the flow does **not** go into `catch(err)`. Rather, it goes into the `then()` as below, which is incorrect.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/submit")
public void submit(@RequestBody CaseInquiry caseInquiry) throws Exception {
    
    // test
    throw new Exception("test");
    
}
```

JS Fetch:

```
const submit = () => {
        fetch("/app/submit", {
            method: "POST", 
            body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(valueMap)),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => { 
            alert('Success'); // Comes here (incorrectly with JSON string)
        }).catch(error => {
            alert('Error: ' + error); // Does not come here
        });
    }
}
```

The `then()` result is

```
'{"timestamp":"2023-08-21T13:07:06.832+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path":"/app/submit"}'
```

I found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353662/1005607) that this JSON output comes from Spring Boot's `BasicErrorController`.

> It's used as a fallback when your application hasn't handled an
> exception using Spring MVC (with an ExceptionHandler or
> ControllerAdvice, for example) or a container error page.

So is there a way for me in Spring Boot to allow exceptions to propagate so that I catch them with `catch()` in the JS Fetch?

Comment: I believe this post will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236296/9862795